# Drawing an array

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw one line with ar[]. It contains the  point cords. I am also trying to use the color described in clr[]. Can any one tell me what is wrong with my ver function. When I run it, only a white screen comes up.

```
 void ver(void)
{

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();


GLfloat ar [] = {0.25, 0.25,
                 0.5, 0.25,

                            };      
GLfloat clr [] = {1.0, 0.0,0.0

};



glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);                        
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT, 0, ar);
glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,clr);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 2, GL_FLOAT, ar);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 3, GL_FLOAT, clr);
    glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `glDrawElements()` is wrong. You need to pass an array of indices to it, and you only need to call it once. So you need something like this:

```
GLuint indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
glDrawElements (GL_LINES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

Also, I think you need to expand your color array to have one color per vertex, so it should look more like:

```
GLfloat clr [] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                   1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
```